# How to test and reach the part of code inside a pipe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having a service that looks more less like this

```
getData(properties: any): Observable<any[]> {
        const qrList$: Observable<any[]> =
            properties.type === 'e'
                ? this.getByE(properties)
                : this.getByD(properties);
        return qrList$.pipe(
            map((qrList) => this.filter(qrList));
    }

private getByE(properties: any): Observable<any[]> {
        let request$: Observable<any[]>;
        if (properties.o === 'c') {
            request$ = this.qrService.getQ();
        } else {
            request$ = this.eService.getEncByE()
                .pipe(
                    map((encList: any[]) => this.getFinished(encList)),
                    switchMap((list) => {
                        return previousEncounterIdList?.length > 0
                            ? this.qrService.getQ()
                            : of([]);
                    }),
                );
        }
        return request$;
    }
```

and my spec file

```
...
    beforeEach(() => {
       spyOn(eService, 'getEncByE').and.returnValue(of([{}]));
       spyOn(qrService, 'getQ').and.returnValue(of([]));

    });

...

    it('whatever', fakeAsync(() => {
        propertiesMock.type = 'e';
        propertiesMock.o = 'p';
    
        service.getData(propertiesMock);
        tick();
    
        expect(eService.getEncByE).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(qrService.getQ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

the last line of code `expect(qrService.getQ).toHaveBeenCalled();` throws an error that the spy was never called, how can I reach this part of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `service.getData()` returns an `Observable`, you have to `subscribe` to it for the subscription to "take flight".

Try this:

```
it('whatever', fakeAsync(() => {
        propertiesMock.type = 'e';
        propertiesMock.o = 'p';
        // mock getEncByE
        spyOn(eService, 'getEncByE').and.returnValue(of([]));
        // have to maybe do some more mocking as well
        service.getData(propertiesMock).subscribe(() => {
           expect(eService.getEncByE).toHaveBeenCalled();
           expect(qrService.getQ).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
        tick();
    }));
```

Comment: you are a 100% correct, silly me :)